# R access row index in apply function

Tags: r, syntax, large-data

I have a large dataset in memory, with approximately 400k rows. Working on a subset of this dataframe, I'd like to generate a large image, and set elements in that image to be equal to a particular value, based on entries in the data frame. I've done this very simply, and undoubtedly stupidly, using a `for` loop:

```
library('Matrix')

#saveMe is a subset of the dataframe containing the x-ranges I want 
#in columns 1,2; y-ranges in 3-4, and values in 5. 
saveMe<-structure(list(XMin = c(1, 17, 19, 19, 21, 29, 29, 31, 31, 31, 31, 33, 33, 35, 37, 39, 39, 39, 41, 43), XMax = c(9, 15, 1, 3,1, 17, 37, 5, 13, 25, 35, 17, 43, 23, 47, 25, 25, 33, 21, 29), YMin = c(225, 305, 435, 481, 209, 1591, 157, 115, 1, 691, 79, 47, 893, 1805, 809, 949, 2179, 1733, 339, 739), YMax = c(277,315, 435, 499, 213, 1689, 217, 133, 1, 707, 111, 33, 903,1827, 849, 973, 2225, 1723, 341, 765), Value = c(3, 1, 0,1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0)), .Names = c("XMin", "XMax", "YMin", "YMax", "Value"),class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

#Create sparse matrix to store the result:
xMax <- max(saveMe$XMax) - min(saveMe$XMin)+1
yMax <- max(saveMe$YMax) - min(saveMe$YMin)+1
img<-Matrix(0, nrow = xMax, ncol = yMax, sparse = TRUE)

for (kx in 1:nrow(saveMe)) {
  img[as.numeric(saveMe[kx,1]):as.numeric(saveMe[kx,2]), as.numeric(saveMe[kx,3]):as.numeric(saveMe[kx,4])] <- as.numeric(saveMe[kx,5])
}
nnzero(img)
image(img)
```

This takes a *really* long time -- about five hours -- and is dumb, iterating row-wise. I know that typically one can use apply to speed things up hugely. So, I've tried to do this, much as you might expect:

```
img<-Matrix(0, nrow = xMax, ncol = yMax, sparse = TRUE)
apFun <- function(x, imToUse){
  #idea is to then change that to something like...
  imToUse[(x[1]:x[2]), (x[3]:x[4]) ] <- x[5]
}  

apply(as.matrix(saveMe), 1, apFun,imToUse=img);
nnzero(img)
image(img)
```

However, whatever I try the resulting elements in `img` are always zero. I think this might be a variable scoping issue. What am I doing wrong?

As an aside, the problem I *really* want to solve is to create an integer "sparse image" for this data, where everything is zero aside from the elements in the rectangle bounded by `[XMin XMax YMin YMax]` which are equal to `value` (i.e. `x[5]`). Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Sathish -- What's a good way to show a data frame in a copyable way on SE?

Comment: see the edit below. I added my overall suggestion and some benchmarks to give you some data re: how to make this more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct.
Try this to convince yourself:

```
f <- function(x){
    x <- 5
}

x <- 4

f(x)
# Nothing is returned
x 
# [1] 4

y <- f(x)
x
# [1] 4
y
# [1] 5
```

For your function, since you're not assigning the result in `apply()`, you want to add the object you updated at the end as the return value.

```
apFun <- function(x, imToUse){
  #idea is to then change that to something like...
  imToUse[(x[1]:x[2]), (x[3]:x[4]) ] <- x[5]
  imToUse
}
```

This is similar to

```
rm(x, y)
f <- function(x){
    x <- 5
    x
}
x <- 4
f(x)
# [1] 5
x
# [1] 4
```

Notice that you are STILL not updating x. But you are returning a value.

EDIT:
On review of the purpose of your function and your call to `apply`, I'd recommend you stick with your original for loop. The intent of your call to `apply` is to update the values in an object in the parent environment. In this case, since the benefit of `apply` is the convenience of a wrapper to a loop and the protection of a local environment, you have to go through a series of contortions, to get out of that protected wrapper.

HOW TO SPEED IT UP:
change your for loop to this

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(saveMe))){
  img[saveMe[[i,1]]:saveMe[[i,2]], saveMe[[i,3]]:saveMe[[i,4]]] <- saveMe[[i,5]]
}
```

Where is that saving you time?  The big time savings here is using `[[` to extract a single value from a data table based on an index rather than using `[`. Here's the data:

You're looking up 5 single values in a data table of 400,000 rows, using the row and column integer index (so that's 2,000,000 lookups in your loop) and assigning an array based on those values 400,000 times. The assignment might be hard to optimize, but the lookup is not. Lets run 100 trials each of a integer index lookup in a data table and an assignment of that single value, comparing the `[` and the `[[` operator.

```
DT <- data.table(x = sample(5000))
single <- replicate(100, {
  system.time({
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(DT))){
      z <- DT[i,1]
    }
  })
})  
double <- replicate(100, {
  system.time({
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(DT))){
      z <- DT[[i,1]]
    }
  })
})

rowMeans(single)
# user.self   sys.self    elapsed user.child  sys.child 
#   1.69405    0.03519    1.89836    0.00000    0.00000 
rowMeans(double)
# user.self   sys.self    elapsed user.child  sys.child 
#   0.05047    0.00083    0.05668    0.00000    0.00000
```

The key value here is `user.self`.  You can see that using the `[[` to extract the value is about 30 times faster, based on 100 trials.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually work for me? I've run it through with the example data above, and `img` still has no non-zero elements?

Comment: You're not updating img with apply. You'll get a new object. This is a good thing. If you want to update an object using `apply()` you have to break some rules about scoping.

Comment: See the example at the end of my answer. `x` is STILL `4`. If you want to use a function to update a variable outside the internal environment of that function, you have to use the `<<-` assignment operator, but you shouldn't do that..

Comment: I'm heading to a meeting, but later I can look at your object and how you're using apply. Incidentally, apply doesn't typically speed up a loop. It's still a loop, it's just in a nice protected wrapper.  This answer is why you don't get a return value from your user defined function.